# How to trigger sass build after mix.copy is completely executed using Laravel-Mix

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, webpack, laravel-mix

I have implemented Laravel-Mix in my application and copying files from node_module to my assets folder and than compiling my scss. Since the copying process is slow my scss is not able to find the dependent libraries.
Is there a way to delay the sass build and trigger it after copying task has completed?

Here is my webpack

```
 let mix = require('laravel-mix');    
 mix.copy('node_modules/ionicons', 'resources/assets/css/libs/ionicons')
 mix.sass('resources/assets/css/sass/app.scss', 'public/dist');
```

Below is my app.scss

```
@import '../libs/ionicons/dist/css/ionicons';
@import 'header';
```

Here is the error I am getting

```
95% emitting ERROR  Failed to compile with 2 errors7:38:04 PM

 error  in ./resources/assets/css/sass/app.scss

Module build failed:
@import '../libs/ionicons/dist/css/ionicons';
^
      File to import not found or unreadable: ../libs/ionicons/dist/css/ionicons.
```

Comment: Import the same module directly from node_modules and remove the copy part of your mix config and it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use tilda importer.
**Webpack** recognize `~` as `projectRoot/node_modules`

**app.scss**

```
@import '~ionicons/dist/css/ionicons.css';
@import 'header';
```

or much better to import sass version, to make it more flexible.

**app.scss**

```
$ionicons-font-path: '~/ionicons/dist/fonts'; //change path to ionicon font

@import '~ionicons/dist/scss/ionicons';
@import 'header';
```

**webpack.mix.js**

```
 let mix = require('laravel-mix');
 mix.sass('resources/assets/css/sass/app.scss', 'public/dist');
```